# How to make scroll content over video?

Tags: html, css

I have background `<video>` on the full page. How can I locate content by center with scrolling over video?

I try to use `div` with hidden scrollbar, but seem it is not write way.

**My HTML code:**

```
<body>
<video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="T.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="T.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
video { display: block; }

    video#bgvid { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: Show yourHTML to check?

Comment: have you added overflow:hidden? if yes remove that.

Comment: Video section is set as fixed. Content over the top with transparent background or within smaller than full width div should do what you want? Show html if that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I have given HTML in question

Comment: This is my test page with background video: http://oleg-s-fresh-site-8f277a.webflow.io/